# Whats the best way to remove Out of Stock text

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, out-of-stock

I'm having trouble displaying the **out of stock size** without text "`Out of Stock`".

Example: [image: Select Size]

And here is how its showing up in DOM:

```
<span class="option out-of-stock" value="370">25 (Out of Stock)</span>
```

Also here is the jQuery piece that adds class to this span:

```
jQuery(".ui-segment span.option:contains('(Out of Stock)')").addClass('out-of-stock');
```

**Is there a way to strip out the text "(Out of Stock)"?**

or can I somehow generate only **Size number** eg:

**"25" without text "Out of Stock"?**
So that instead of 25 Out of Stock it displays as 25

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a config in admin to don't display the `Out of stock products` **System>configuration>catalog>inventory>Display out of stock products>NO**
2. If you want to hide the sizes that contains out of stock, you can do it like this:

**HTML:**

```
<span><p>25</p></span>
<span><p>26 out of stock</p></span>
<span><p>27</p></span>
<span><p>28 out of stock</p></span>
```

**JS:**

```
$.expr[":"].containsNoCase = function(el, i, m) {
    var search = m[3];
    if (!search) return false;
    var pattern = new RegExp(search,"i");
    return pattern.test($(el).text());
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span p:containsNoCase('out of stock')").parent('span').hide();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aa3601vt/1/)

Comment: I have tried System>configuration>catalog>inventory>Display out of stock products>NO but this doesnt remove "Out of Stock" text.

As per js approach it removes the size numbers as well, which I need to preserve.

Comment: No, look my jsfiddle demo, if the span contain the 'out of stock' sting, he hide it, you have to customise the js according your div, span, id etc...

Comment: I'm sure your answer makes sense, but unfortunately I'm not very literate in js, jQuery and I'm unable to remove only "Out of Stock" and keep the existing numbers  (( e.g 25, 26, 27, 28 it removes the entire span and leaves me with 25, 27

Comment: Look your question : `can I somehow generate only Size number for out of stock products` ! your question is rather blurred

Comment: I have edited question, hope it makes more sense.

Comment: I'm thinking to get the text and do jQuery replace function, idk if this is an efficient way to handle such issue.

Example: jQuery(".ui-segment span.option").text().replace(' Out of Stock', ' ');

Answer (score 0):

You can remove out of stock text from file

> app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches.phtml

in this file look for code something like `$_option->label` and with this code if there is  any static text added for **(Out of Stock)** , you can simply comment or remove that text.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't have these files neither in basse, default or my_package.

Comment: Are you using any extension for attribute swatches?

Comment: I'm sure there is a customization from previous developer. I just cannot find that piece of code which generates that string. I used commerce bug, template hints,  etc. cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
jQuery(".ui-segment span.out-of-stock").text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(' (Out of Stock)', '');
});
```